# Constructing independent random variables based on non-independent ones

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Given $n$ random variables $X_{i}:(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}) \to (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$, suppose that $X_{i}$ takes value only zero or one, and we have $n$ tuple $(b_{i})_{1\leq i\leq n}$ such that $\mathbb{P}(X_{i} = 1) \leq b_{i}$. These random variables are not independent, but I think my professor said something along the following to construct $n$ independent random variables.

> Let $Y_{i}: (\Omega,\mathcal{F,\mathbb{P}}) \to (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ be random variables that only take value 0 and 1. On $\{ X_{i} = 1 \}$, we set $Y_{i} = 1$. and additionally on $\{ X_{i} = 0 \}$, we have $\mathbb{P}(\{ Y_{i}=1 \} \cap \{ X_{i} = 0 \}) = b_{i} - \mathbb{P}(X_{i})$. Then $\mathbb{P}(Y_{i}=1) = b_{i}$, and he claimed that $(Y_{i})_{1\leq i\leq n}$ are independent.

Intuitively this makes sense, but he did not explicitly construct $Y_{i}$ as a random variable (on $\{ X_{i} = 0 \}$), and I cannot think of a proof on why this is true.

I'm dramatically simplifying the details, for more context, see [Lemma 21.2.4 (a) here](https://courses.grainger.illinois.edu/cs574/sp2024/lec/notes/lec/21_two_choices.pdf). I used different variable names as well.

Comment: I don't see how it makes sense. Suppose $n=2$, $\mathbb{P}(X_1=1)={1\over 2} = b_1 = b_2$ and $X_1 = X_2$. Now, it looks like $Y_1 = X_1$ and $Y_2=X_2$ by such construction. I might be missing something.

Comment: @Atbey Then I don't know what is going on. It's page 4 of the document I linked and the notation is $Y_i$ and $Y_{i}'$ I'm probably oversimplifying then.